# Multiple Tables, Abstract class , Entity Types

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

CS.

```
    public abstract  class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsCorporate { get; set; }
    }

    public class PrivateCustomer: Customer
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfContract { get; set; }
        public int QuoteAmmount { get; set; }
        public string PromotionCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class BusinesCustomer: Customer
    {
        public string BusinessName { get; set; }
        public string BusinessAddress { get; set; }
        public TypeofContract ContractType { get; set; }
        public DateTime ContractStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime ContractEnd { get; set; }
    }

    public enum TypeofContract
    {
        Hourly =1,
        Daily = 2,
        Weekly = 3

    }
```

DB Storage =
[image: DB Entity Design Existing]

Saw some example : http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC315206.gif where they have done the Course -> OnlineCourse and OnsiteCourse couldnt find the c# layer for it.

any one has any idea on how do i solve this in EF code first approach.

Kind Regards
Vinay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solves the issue just by declaring a table header.

```
public abstract  class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorporate { get; set; }
}

[Table("PrivateCustomer")]
public class PrivateCustomer: Customer
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfContract { get; set; }
    public int QuoteAmmount { get; set; }
    public string PromotionCode { get; set; }
}

[Table("BusinesCustomer")]
public class BusinesCustomer: Customer
{
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string BusinessAddress { get; set; }
    public TypeofContract ContractType { get; set; }
    public DateTime ContractStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime ContractEnd { get; set; }
}

public enum TypeofContract
{
    Hourly =1,
    Daily = 2,
    Weekly = 3

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Way i get around this is

Remove the abstract class , and make it an entity, and then use one to one mappin for threst of the two entities.

but storage was solved still the problem of what type it creates is not solved. you cannot get a list  to walk through.

found this link where the guru explains this :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100109/Mixing-Table-Per-Hierarchy-and-Entity-Splitting.aspx

but how do i do it POCO. Code first approach?
Any ideas welcome.